# Re-expose BLL methods in Service Layer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, soa

Just doing some research for my next project and what I would like to know is whether we should take our BLL and just clone each action into a service contract? Or whether we should write new methods....?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best choice depends on how tightly coupled you want your BLL to be to your Service Layer. [Loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) is a quality metric of strong software design. For this reason, I'd recommend you create new methods to keep the BLL loosely coupled to your Service Layer.